# Using node.js to recognize when Arduino Micro is plugged into USB

Tags: node.js, node-serialport

First off, I'm new to both node.js and the concept of async functions and would greatly appreciate any help I can get here.
I've been trying to write a script using the node.js serialport module to scan the ports on my Windows machine and do simple stuff once an Arduino Micro is connected to a port. The below works fine if the Arduino is already connected, but I can't work out how to extend it so that it will wait, indefinitely, until the Micro is plugged in. It just terminates if nothing is found.

```
const serialPort = require('serialport');
var portName;

serialPort.list().then(function(ports){
    ports.forEach(function(portInfo){
        if (portInfo.vendorId == 2341 && portInfo.productId == 8037) {
            portName = portInfo.path;
            var myPort = new serialPort(portName);
            myPort.on('open' , function() {
                showPortOpen();
                myPort.write('RL');   // command to initiate functions in Arduino code
            });
            myPort.on('data' , readSerialData);    // echo data from Arduino
            myPort.on('close', showPortClose);
        }
    })
});

function readSerialData(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

function showPortOpen() {
    console.log(portName,'opened');
}

function showPortClose() {
    console.log(portName,'closed');
}
```

Comment: Call your `serialPort.list()...` in a `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`

Comment: Thanks man! I knew it would be easy. I just tried setInterval, clearing it once the port is found and it works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved in double-quick time. Thank you :-)

Not sure if it's the cleanest approach but by re-calling the setInterval function when the port closes, I have a script that waits and finds the Arduino once it's plugged into the USB and, if subsequently unplugged, will find it again once it's plugged in again. Just what I want!

```
const serialPort = require('serialport');
var portName;

loop();   // start searching for Arduino on a port

function loop() {
    loopId = setInterval(function() {
        serialPort.list().then(function(ports){
            ports.forEach(function(portInfo){
                if (portInfo.vendorId == 2341 && portInfo.productId == 8037) {
                    portName = portInfo.path;
                    var myPort = new serialPort(portName);
                    myPort.on('open' , function() {
                        showPortOpen();
                        myPort.write('RL');   // command to initiate Arduino functions
                    });
                    myPort.on('data' , readSerialData);   // echo data from Arduino
                    myPort.on('close', showPortClose);
                }
            })
        })
    }, 1000)
};

function readSerialData(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

function showPortOpen() {
    console.log(portName,'opened');
    clearInterval(loopId);   // stop looping once Arduino found on port
}

function showPortClose() {
    console.log(portName,'closed');
    loop();   // start over when Arduino port is closed
}
```

Comment: Great work! It looks like you have a good grasp of asynchronous/event-oriented programming. Should serve you well in javascript-land.